# Add ripple effect to a custom gesture in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I try to create a tappable surface in Jetpack Compose where the elevation changes when the user taps the surface. The following code already works:

```
var tapped by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
val elevation by animateDpAsState(
    targetValue = if (tapped) 0.dp else 5.dp,
    animationSpec = tween(50)
)

Surface(
    shape = RoundedCornerShape(20.dp),
    modifier = Modifier
         .padding(16.dp)
         .requiredSize(150.dp)
         .pointerInput(Unit) {
              detectTapGestures(onPress = {
              tapped = true

              tryAwaitRelease()

              tapped = false
         })
    },
    elevation = elevation
) {
  ...
}
```

However I would like to have a ripple effect during the tap. How could I achieve this?

The default button/surface `onClick` and `clickable` is not suitable because it only handles press inputs but no taps.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You use [`Modifier.indication`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/package-summary/#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).indication(androidx.compose.foundation.interaction.InteractionSource,androidx.compose.foundation.Indication)) to add ripple effect, and pass events with `interactionSource` to update it state like this:

```
var tapped by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }

Surface(
    modifier = Modifier
        .indication(interactionSource, LocalIndication.current)
        .pointerInput(Unit) {
            detectTapGestures(onPress = { offset ->
                tapped = true

                val press = PressInteraction.Press(offset)
                interactionSource.emit(press)

                tryAwaitRelease()

                interactionSource.emit(PressInteraction.Release(press))

                tapped = false
            })
        }
) {
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately the clickable Modifier only handles a press interaction when the item is pressed (not tapped). See Modifier.clickable() implementation.

Comment: @oldu see my `println("handle tap")`, you can handle the tap there. In your sample code `tapped` is true during long press too, not only on tap.

Comment: Oh yes you're right! The problem seems to be in the interaction flow. I now delayed the `tapped = false` for a few milliseconds and i can see that press is called. Unfortunately in the UI there is a little delay between the tap of the button and the elevation animation. This delay prevents from a smooth user interaction.

Comment: @oldu I've updated my answer with example of ripple effect on a custom gesture