# how to animate button click in jetpack compose without consuming the click event

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I saw similar questions with no great solutions so I thought this might be useful.

I had a problem when I wanted to animate a button the user clicked to make it larger when pressed; not as easy as it sounds because when you get the animation working the onClick event never fires.  [Because it depends on the up event I guess]

I found a way to make both the animation and the click work for a icon button and I thought it might work for other cases.

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalComposeUiApi::class)
@Composable
fun RoundIconButton(
modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
imageVector: ImageVector,
onClick: () -> Unit,
tint: Color = Color.Black.copy(alpha = 0.8f),
backgroundColor: Color = 
MaterialTheme.colors.background,
elevation: Dp = 4.dp,
contentDescription: String

) {
val interactionSource = remember { 
MutableInteractionSource() }
val isPressed by 
interactionSource.collectIsPressedAsState()
val transition = updateTransition(targetState 
 = isPressed, label = "")

val size by transition.animateDp(label = "") 
{ state ->
    when(state) {
        false -> 40.dp
        true -> 50.dp
    }
}

Card(
    modifier = modifier
        .padding(all = 4.dp)
        .clickable(interactionSource = 
interactionSource,indication = 
LocalIndication.current,onClick= onClick)
    .then(Modifier.size(size)),
    shape = CircleShape,
    backgroundColor = backgroundColor,
    elevation = elevation,


) {
    Icon( imageVector = imageVector, 
contentDescription = contentDescription,tint 
= tint)
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the question

Comment: I asked it because i needed to do it and found no good questions and answered it. thought others might find it useful. Compose is cool but new

Comment: Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69754118/3585796) answer for how to add ripple animation to custom gesture and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68878910/3585796) for how to detect tap without consuming it

Comment: @keepTrackOfYourStack if this Question already contains the answer why not add it as an actual answer and mark it as solved. That way the answer is easier to recognize