# How to exclude a clickable element from the tab order

Tags: kotlin, accessibility, compose-desktop

With Jetpack Compose for Desktop, we can make pretty much any element clickable:

```
Text("I'm clickable", Modifier.clickable { onClick() })
```

This causes the element to be included in the tab order, and most of the time that's what you want. But in my case, the interaction that happens on click is also available in another way, so I don't want to force the user to tab through a lot of useless `Text`s.

How can I exclude the clickable element from the tab order?

Comment: Any element that has a click handler needs to be focusable. See also https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Understanding/keyboard. In Web applications, if a lot of focusable elements would be cumbersome to tab through, a _composit widget_ is established, which only has one tab stop. Switching between items is then done via arrow keys. Maybe that’s an alternative approach to your issue… Otherwise, skip links might be interesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Modifier.clickable` is a high-level API, you can use a lower-level API to get more flexibility.

To detect tap you can use `Modifier.pointerInput` with `detectTapGestures`:

```kotlin
Modifier
    .pointerInput(Unit) {
        detectTapGestures {
            onClick()
        }
    }
```

Many of the things clickable does won't be added in this case. For example, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69754118/3585796) on how to add a ripple effect. See `Modifier.clickable` [source code](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/d1ae3a679f2a873998579f61ac13f4ec06799a02/compose/foundation/foundation/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/Clickable.kt#L128) for other things you may need to add.

Comment: Do you know which part of that code causes inclusion in the tab order? Nothing in the implementation jumps out to me, it's all about tapping and pressing, not about tab order or focusing.

Comment: @Jorn I think my link to the source code is not very valid - when I navige to `clickable` definition in IDEA, I see the use of the `focusRequesterAndModifier` function, which probably causes this behavior, but I have not found it in android compose or in the compose-jb repositories, so I cannot provide a link.